Please identify this program for Acorn Archimedes
From the movie Murder Story
This is the pc (is 90% Acorn Archimedes 305)

This is the program

another view

Anyone recognize name of program? Thanks
The os can be Arthur OS or RISC-OS

That would be 1st Word Plus.  This blog contains a full screenshot of it in use (via an emulator).
